# Getting blank line when reading from file into a constructor

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I'm having trouble when reading to a file, I can get it to read all lines but uses the fist piece of info from the next line or it will add a blank line at the end confusing the array of constructors.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class StudentMain {
/**
 * @param args
 */

//(String fn, String ln, String pn, int id, boolean ft, int phn, boolean lj, String     con)
    //array and sorting variables
 public static studentConstructor[] stuArrayOrig;
 private static String[] stuArrayIdSort;
 private static String[] stuArrayNameSort;
 private static int i = 0;
 private static int lineCount = 0;
 private static int nElms = 0;
 //studentConstructor variables 
    public static String fn; //First Name
    public static String ln; //Last Name
    public static String pn; //Preferred Name
    public static int id;     //Student Id Number
    public static boolean ft;//Full-time Boolean
    public static int phn;   //Student Phone Number
    public static boolean lj;//Loving java Boolean
    public static String con;//Continuing 


 public static void StuRead()
 {

    Scanner inFile = null;
     try
     {
         inFile = new Scanner
                (new FileReader("Res/students.txt"));
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e)
     {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         System.out.println("File Not Found");
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

        while (inFile.hasNextLine()){
                    inFile.useDelimiter(",|\\n"); //breaks the   lines into single info

                    ln = inFile.next();
                        System.out.println(ln);

                    fn = inFile.next();
                        System.out.println(fn);

                    pn = inFile.next();
                        System.out.println(pn);

                    id = inFile.nextInt();
                        System.out.println(id);

                    ft = inFile.nextBoolean();
                        System.out.println(ft);

                    phn = inFile.nextInt();
                        System.out.println(phn);

                    lj = inFile.nextBoolean();
                        System.out.println(lj);

                    con = inFile.next();
                        System.out.println(con);

                        studentConstructor st = new studentConstructor(ln, fn, pn, id, ft, phn, lj, con);
                        System.out.println(st);
                        //System.out.println("LINE");
                        stuArrayOrig[lineCount] = st;
                        inFile.nextLine();
                        System.out.println(stuArrayOrig[lineCount]);


                    lineCount++;`
```

Example input from file:

```
Angelon Arouca,Lucas,,1472429,TRUE,407514687,TRUE,Confirmed
Cordovilla,Wilbert,,1472430,TRUE,407514688,FALSE,Confirmed
Danks,Joshua,,1472431,TRUE,407514689,TRUE,Confirmed
```

And the output I get:

```
Angelon Arouca
Lucas

1472429
true
407514687
true
Confirmed

studentConstructor@29ba92bb
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at StudentMain.StuRead(StudentMain.java:73)
at StudentApp.main(StudentApp.java:10)
```

Can anyone see where I went wrong?

Comment: So what are expecting? You have used `,` as Delimiter and there is empty string between commas. Simply check the length and continue the loop. Just skip it.

Answer (score 2):

You never initialized `stuArrayOrig`, so it's `null`, and trying to access it cause a `NullPointerException`.

Once approach would be to initialize it to some "safe" large value:

```
public static studentConstructor[] stuArrayOrig = new studentConstructor[100];
```

But it would probably be much easier to just use a self-growing `ArrayList`:

```
public static List<studentConstructor> stuArrayOrig = new ArrayList<>();
```